# Find out who's using all the bandwidth on a Windows 2008 Terminal Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, terminal-server

We have a couple of Server 2008 terminal servers on the network and we do some basic network monitoring on the firewall to find out which computers are abusing the internet bandwidth. What we haven't workout how to do yet is to monitor which users on a terminal server are abusing the bandwith with the data displayed as a list of mb/gb per day or per minute for each port.

What I would like to know (as we have little funds at the moment) is if there is any cheap software (maybe even desktop) that can monitor each users bandwith and maybe produce the kind of information I am looking for above. Even just basic information on how much data each user

Answer (score 3):

Resource Manager doesn't do what you're looking for?

Network usage: process, source computer address and bandwidth consumed.  Not exactly an amazing monitoring tool, but it's part of Server 2008, and seems to me like it would give you more than enough information to find your bandwidth hog and hit him with the BOFH hammer.

[image: Resource Monitor]

Comment: Yes it's a good tool, but then I need a way to find which process' are linked to which users and add up their bandwidth manually. And that means I can't have a live view of users current bandwidth usage.

Comment: You may be overthinking this.  When you get alerts about (or notice?) high bandwidth at your firewall, jump on the server and fire up Resource Monitor.  Smart money says you'll have source(s) of the problem pretty quick.  The only particularly easy way to do exactly what you're asking for is with a proxy/firewall your users have to go through to get anywhere ***AND*** requires authentication (so it can track sessions by user).  They're a pain in the ass, and at least on Windows are not cheap or free, so this may be the best option available to you.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps this one will suit you: [10-Strike Bandwidth Monitor](http://www.10-strike.com/bandwidth-monitor/)

it collects inbound and  outbound bandwidth data from each network interface and displays the results in graphics: per day, per month, per hour. So you could view easily who uses up all the bandwidth on the network

(sorry, I cant post the image,coz i am new here)